# Extract root domain as well as the TLD in Google sheets regexextract

Tags: google-sheets

I need to extract the root domain as well as the TLD for a list or url's. Ive tried other formulas on Satckoverflow but they don't work.

As an example i want to only extract 'example' from all these permutations (as well as other available TLD's e.g .biz, .eu etc):

```
https://www.example.com
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.co.uk
http://example.co.uk
http://www.example.co.uk
https://www.example.org
http://example.org
http://www.example.org
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works ?

```
=ArrayFormula(regexextract(A2:A10, "https?\://(?:www\.)?(.*?)\."))
```

Change range to suit.

[image]